# Ramda js maximum elements

Tags: ramda.js

I wonder how will be the best way to get max elements from array.

For example I have regions with temperaturs:

```
let regions = [{name: 'alabama', temp: 20}, {name: 'newyork', temp: 30}...];
```

It can be done with one line but I want to be performant.

I want to iterate over the array only once.

**If more than 1 region has the same max temperature i want to get them all**

Do you know a way to make it with more compact code than procedure code with temporary variables and so on.

If it can be done in "functional programming" way it will be very good.

This is sample procedure code:

```
regions = [{name:'asd', temp: 13},{name: 'fdg', temp: 30}, {name: 'asdsd', temp: 30}]
maxes = []
max = 0
for (let reg of regions) {
    if (reg.temp > max) {
        maxes = [reg];
        max = reg.temp
    } else if (reg.temp == max) {
        maxes.push(reg)
    } else {
        maxes =[]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use R.pipe to

1. Group the objects by `temp`'s value,
2. Convert the object of groups to an array of pairs
3. Reduce the pairs to the one with the max key (the `temp`)
4. return the value from the pair

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, toPairs, reduce, maxBy, head, last } = R;

const regions = [
  {name: 'california', temp: 30},
  {name: 'alabama', temp: 20},
  {name: 'newyork', temp: 30}
];

const result = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('temp')),
  toPairs,
  reduce(maxBy(pipe(head, Number)), [-Infinity]),
  last
)(regions);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: looks greate and simple :), but does it really iterate over the array only once? Doesnt it need to first group and then reduce?

Comment: It iterates once over the array to create the groups, than once over the groups (there can be a group for each item) to convert to pairs, another over the groups to get the highest - which O(3n) -> O(n).

Comment: Yes good answer, but it will be a little slower than procedure approach, correct right?

Comment: Probably. It might be negligible, depending on the amount of items in the array.

Comment: There is a problem with this, which you can see if you change the `30`s to `101`s.  To fix it, you could replace `maxBy(head)` with `maxBy(compose(Number, head))`.  But along the way, this is losing some simplicity.

Comment: The example is 3times slower which is problem. I want only 1 iteration for the array.

Comment: I can do it with filter(x => x == Math.max(regions.map(r => r.temp)) but this defeats the purpose of the question where i want only 1 iteration over the whole array. The code is simpler which is perfect but performance is not as in procedure sample.

Comment: Is this 3x difference an actual issue in your application?  Of course it could be.  If you're doing this tens of thousand times a second, maybe there's a real difference here.  But as always, "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Mm, in one case not, but imagine i use this function 3 times in a web request (for other data in json for example). Multiply that by users request per seconds and it gets issue fast :)

Comment: What I was suggesting is that you measure it before you start optimizing for performance.  Use the simplest code you can (without being totally stupid about performance, of course) and make sure you're fast enough.  If not, measure to find out what your real bottlenecks are, and optimize the worst ones until you reach reasonable performance.  It's amazing how often no performance tuning is needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Another Ramda approach:

```js
const {reduce, append} = R

const regions = [{name:'asd', temp: 13},{name: 'fdg', temp: 30}, {name: 'asdsd', temp: 30}]

const maxTemps = reduce(
  (tops, curr) => curr.temp > tops[0].temp ? [curr] : curr.temp === tops[0].temp ? append(curr, tops) : tops,
  [{temp: -Infinity}]
)

console.log(maxTemps(regions))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

This version only iterates the list once.  But it's a bit ugly.

I would usually prefer the version from Ori Drori unless testing shows that the performance is a problem in my application.  Even with the fix from my comment, I think that code is easier to understand than this one.  (That wouldn't be true if there were only two cases.  (`<` versus `>=` for instance.)  But when there are three, this gets hard to read, however we might format it.

But if performance is really a major issue, then your original code is probably faster than this one too.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i wish i could find functional approach with the same performace but sometimes its uglier than procedure code. I hope I will find it someday :)). Anyway the answer is good thanks

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to this (albeit a little more verbose) is to create some helpers to generically take care of folding over a list of things to extract the list of maximums.

We can do this by defining a [Semigroup](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#semigroup) wrapper class (could also be a plain function instead of a class).

```
const MaxManyBy = fn => class MaxMany {
  constructor(values) {
    this.values = values
  }
  concat(other) {
    const otherValue = fn(other.values[0]),
          thisValue  = fn(this.values[0])

    return otherValue > thisValue ? other
         : otherValue < thisValue ? this
         : new MaxMany(this.values.concat(other.values))
  }
  static of(x) {
    return new MaxMany([x])
  }
}
```

The main purpose of this class is to be able to combine two lists by comparing the values contained within, with the invariant that each list contains the same comparable values.

We now can introduce a new helper function which applies some function to each value of a list and then combines them all using `concat`.

```
const foldMap = (fn, [x, ...xs]) =>
  xs.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(fn(next)), fn(x))
```

With these helpers, we can now create a function that pulls the maximum temperatures from your example.

```
const maxTemps = xs =>
  foldMap(MaxManyBy(({temp}) => temp).of, xs).values

maxTemps([
  {name: 'california', temp: 30},
  {name: 'alabama', temp: 20},
  {name: 'newyork', temp: 30}
])
//=> [{"name": "california", "temp": 30}, {"name": "newyork", "temp": 30}]
```

There is an assumption here that the list being passed to `foldMap` is non-empty. If there's a chance that you'll encounter an empty list then you will need to modify accordingly to return a default value of some kind (or wrap it in a `Maybe` type if no sane default exists).

See the complete snippet below.

```js
const MaxManyBy = fn => class MaxMany {
  constructor(values) {
    this.values = values
  }
  concat(other) {
    const otherValue = fn(other.values[0]),
          thisValue  = fn(this.values[0])

    return otherValue > thisValue ? other
         : otherValue < thisValue ? this
         : new MaxMany(this.values.concat(other.values))
  }
  static of(x) {
    return new MaxMany([x])
  }
}

const foldMap = (fn, [x, ...xs]) =>
  xs.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(fn(next)), fn(x))

const maxTemps = xs =>
  foldMap(MaxManyBy(({temp}) => temp).of, xs).values

const regions = [
  {name: 'california', temp: 30},
  {name: 'alabama', temp: 20},
  {name: 'newyork', temp: 30}
]

console.log(maxTemps(regions))
```